# Restrict websocket connection to one per user

Tags: php, websocket

is there any way, to do that?.

Basically, i want to restrict logged user (login with sessions in php) to one tab / browser window.

If he has already one connection (opened tab/ window), i don't wanna allow opening another one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you open websocket, record in session an indication that the websocket session is open ($_SESSION['websocket_is_open'] = true), and check it every time the user tries to open a new websocket.

Comment: I't is a nice idea, I will definitely try it, but what i'm looking for  is a way to do that on websocket server script if possible.